# WebFlux session handling

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-session

I have a web application using the following Setup:
Spring Boot 2.4.x
Spring Session
Spring Security
Spring Webflux

We want to use a basic auth authentication, backed with a session. For storing the session I use Spring-Session with a Hazelcast Map, which seems to work (At least there is something stored in the map after login).

I have the following problem: Even though my application creates a Cookie (Set-Cookie header is set in the response), the session isn't loaded on the next call. The Cookie is correctly sent but not taken into account at all.

Config is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().anonymous()
                .and().httpBasic()
                     .securityContextRepository(new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository())
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .build();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableSpringWebSession
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver() {
        return new CookieWebSessionIdResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveSessionRepositoryHazelcast reactiveSessionRepository(
            final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return new ReactiveSessionRepositoryHazelcast(hazelcastInstance);
    }
}
```

And with this config on every request the basic authentication is performed (user is loaded from database, a session is created, new cookie is set in the response). No matter if there is already a cookie sent in the request or not.

edit: The problem does not belong to our self-implemented `ReactiveSessionRepositoryHazelcast`. In fact the corresponding methods on the session repository are not called at all and the problem also persists when using MapReactiveSessionRepository provided by spring-session

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: from where does 'ReactiveSessionRepositoryHazelcast ' come?

Comment: It's something self implemented. But this is for sure not the problem, since the problem also persists when I am using a simple MapReactiveSessionRepository provided by spring-session. I will edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I have a similar setup with redis which works fine. Used annotation is different for redis. But for ReactiveMapSessionRepository your annotation should work fine. You do not need to declare a bean if you wish to use CookieWebSessionIdResolver, which is the default one. Remove that and test. If that also doesn't work and if you are using a spring starter parent try a different version. Let us know what happen.

Comment: Is the client sending basic authentication on every request? If so, the basic authentication credentials will be preferred over any session information that is passed in.

Comment: @RobWinch why is that the case? That's weird and not consistent with the workflow from the normal Spring WebMVC at all. There the session information has precedence and the basic authentication information will only be taken into account if there is no valid session associated with the request.

Comment: You are right it is inconsistent. You will also notice that Spring Security doesn't create a session by default when using HTTP Basic with a WebFlux application. These are considered improvements because generally HTTP Basic is stateless and sending basic authentication is considered more deliberate for which user should be leveraged than sending a session id from a cookie.